# Inconsistent number of Observers on two different method calls to Observable

Tags: java, observable

I'm trying to use observable in my code and there is this problem giving me hard time.

```
public class observeState extends Observable
{
    public void setSelectedTransaction(int idx)
    {
        if (selectedTransaction != idx)
        {
            this.selectedTransaction = idx;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers("setSelectedTransaction");
            System.out.println("Observers : "+this.countObservers());
        }
    }

    public void setLog(Log log)
    {
        if(theLog != log) {
            theLog = log;
            System.out.println(theLog.getLogTransactions().size() + "setLog");
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers("setLog");
            System.out.println("Observers : "+this.countObservers());
        }
    }
```

There are two observers observing this observable class and it does send out `notifyObservers` when the `setSelectedTransaction` method is called with the test line "Observers : 2". However the next method `setLog` does not seem to have observers giving "Observers : 0". I don't think I can only use observable method once.

Comment: Maybe `setChanged()` is doing something weird? Also, double check that `this`is pointing to what you think it is pointing to.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion Keyser :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mostly likely cause of this issue is that you are not calling the method on the same object.  It is a common mistake to assume two objects are the same because they have the same name or some other confusion.  I would print out the hashCode of each object or use a debugger to ensure you really are calling the same object.

BTW you can try making the calls in the opposite order, or more than once
 to test your theory.

Comment: also there is a possibility that the observers are removing themselves as observers on call to notify. Check that too!

Comment: Thanks guys. You are so right, somehow I've kept creating new object when I call some method. Thanks for all your views and what should I do when the question to the answer is not related to the title of question? should I remove it?

Comment: An observer can remove itself while iterating over the observers without an error being raise. i.e. it doesn't check for COncurrentModificationException

Comment: @EugeneYu You can make the title more relevant or you can leave it.  You are not the first, or last to make this mistake so it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Either the **objects** that you are using to call the `setSelectedTransaction` and `setLog` are **different** or the observers might be **removing** themselves as observers in the update method.

Comment: Thank you for the possible answer :)